# "Error: Maximum number of connections from user+IP exceeded" with Mailinabox IMAP and Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, imap, nodemailer

I am running a node.js program through Heroku and using IMAP to check a [Mailinabox](http://mailinabox.email/) inbox every minute. However, when I run the program for more than an hour, I get this message:

```
 Error: Maximum number of connections from user+IP exceeded (mail_max_userip_connections=40) at Connection._resTagged (/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:1502:11)
 at Parser.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:194:10)
etc
```

My program essentially creates a function like this (similar to the example [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imap)):

```
    function checkmail() = {
var imap = new Imap({
  user: 'myusername@mywebsite.com',
  password: 'mypassword',
  host: 'imap.mywebsite.com',
  port: myport,
  tls: true
});
 
function openInbox(cb) {
  imap.openBox('INBOX', true, cb);
}
 
imap.once('ready', function() {
  openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var f = imap.seq.fetch('1:3', {
      bodies: 'HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)',
      struct: true
    });
    f.on('message', function(msg, seqno) {
      //additional processing
     
    });
    f.once('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
    });
    f.once('end', function() {
      console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
      imap.end();
    });
  });
});
 
imap.once('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
 
imap.once('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection ended');
});
    }
```

And then runs the function every minute with a CronJob like this:

```
new CronJob('0 * * * * *', function() {  
    checkmail();
});
```

Do I need to change something about these functions in order to make it not exceed the maximum number of connections? A couple more facts:

- Because I'm using Heroku, I believe the requesting IP address isn't the same for every request.
- I was able to do this using Gmail OK, but I'm having issues setting it up with Mailinabox. I don't see anything in the specifications there about how to increase the number of allowed requests.

Comment: Close your connection when you are done checking the mail

Comment: I am already closing the connection with imap.end(). I've expanded the code to include this part.